# Problema al imprimir objeto de Javascript en consola de navegador

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Estoy aprendiendo Javascrip pero tengo problemas con un objeto

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        const jhon = {
            nombre: "Jhon",
            apellido: "Perez",
            edad: 44,
            pasatiempos: ["bailar", "karate", "correr"],
            contacto:{
                correo: "plazamarco@gmail.com",
                twitter: "@la_guairama",
                telefono: "0212-337"
            },
            saludar: function(){
                console.log("Hola como estas ${this.nombre}");
            }
            /* decirMiNombre: function(){
                console.log('Hola mi nombre es ${this.nombre} ${this.apellido y tengo ${this.edad} años.')
            } */


        }

        console.log(jhon);
        console.log(jhon.nombre);
        console.log(jhon.pasatiempos[1]);
        console.log(jhon.contacto.telefono);
        console.log(jhon.saludar);
        jhon.saludar();
        //jhon.decirMiNombre();

    </script>
```

Al ejecutar la linea 13 en vez de imprimirme el mensaje "Hola como estas Jhon" se me ejecuta de "Hola como estas ${this.nombre}"

Y la linea 16 la cuan tengo deshabilitada de plano me da un error en la consola. No se que estoy haciendo mal ya que estoy aprendiendo por un video tutorial de Youtube. Alguien me podría señalar cuales son mis errores y como corregirlos. Gracias y disculpen la molestia.

Answer (score 2):

Para combinar cadenas y variables debes usar [Plantillas literales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Simplemente, cambia las comillas dobles por comillas invertidas.

Algo así:

```
console.log(`Hola como estas ${this.nombre}`);
```

Veamos una prueba:

```js
const jhon = {
            nombre: "Jhon",
            apellido: "Perez",
            edad: 44,
            pasatiempos: ["bailar", "karate", "correr"],
            contacto:{
                correo: "plazamarco@gmail.com",
                twitter: "@la_guairama",
                telefono: "0212-337.17.11"
            },
            saludar: function(){
                console.log(`Hola como estas ${this.nombre}`);
            }
            /* decirMiNombre: function(){
                console.log('Hola mi nombre es ${this.nombre} ${this.apellido y tengo ${this.edad} años.')
            } */


        }

        console.log(jhon);
        console.log(jhon.nombre);
        console.log(jhon.pasatiempos[1]);
        console.log(jhon.contacto.telefono);
        //console.log(jhon.saludar);
        jhon.saludar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando quieres poner `${...}` en una cadena, tienes que usar las comillas invertidas (**``**). No puede ser ni con las comillas dobles (`""`) o las comillas simples (`''`)

```
console.log(`Hola como estas ${this.nombre}`);
```

Y luego, en la función `decirMiNombre()`, si te fijas, le falta la coma al terminar la función de saludar y un `}` al terminar `this.apellido`.

Aquí está el código aplicando estas correcciones:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  const jhon = {
    nombre: "Jhon",
    apellido: "Perez",
    edad: 44,
    pasatiempos: ["bailar", "karate", "correr"],
    contacto: {
      correo: "plazamarco@gmail.com",
      twitter: "@la_guairama",
      telefono: "0212-337"
    },
    saludar: function () {
      console.log(`Hola como estas ${this.nombre}`);
    },
    decirMiNombre: function () {
      console.log(`Hola mi nombre es ${this.nombre} ${this.apellido} y tengo ${this.edad} años.`)
    }
  }

  console.log(jhon);
  console.log(jhon.nombre);
  console.log(jhon.pasatiempos[1]);
  console.log(jhon.contacto.telefono);
  console.log(jhon.saludar);
  jhon.saludar();
  jhon.decirMiNombre();
  
</script>
```

¡Espero te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

El código Java Script que has compartido contiene un error de sintaxis. El error se encuentra en la función saludar() del objeto jhon. En lugar de usar comillas simples para delimitar la cadena de texto en el console.log, se están utilizando backticks ( ), que son comillas de plantilla.

Aquí está la línea con el error corregido:

```
console.log('Hola mi nombre es ${this.nombre} ${this.apellido} y tengo ${this.edad} años.');
```

Comment: Hola Emin, gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos. ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)